# XCode: debugging mac app window is always on top across applications

Tags: xcode, macos

I am developing an Mac OS app, and have preference window presented as model. This works just fine as I want and I don't want to change that behaviour. The problem is: when the window is shown, and I debug on some breakpoints, the preference window is still there, however, Xcode's app is in focused now, but the preference window from the current app still shows on top. This is annoying. I have to drag it to somewhere to see the Xcode window. Is there anything that I can do so that if the app is in debug mode, then that preference window should also be gone away with my app in background and just Xcode is in foreground?[image]

Comment: I doubt there is much you can do, especially if you don't want to change the flags for the window.  I doubt you'll spend very much time debugging the code for that window anyway...

Comment: @Droppy: I frequently need to debug that window and dragging that window every time is annoying.

Comment: Then you must change the flags when running a debug build and some other flag is set (i.e. a constant).  You cannot not be annoyed and not make changes.

Answer (score 0):

When a window is run as a modal window, its window level is set to `NSModalPanelWindowLevel`, which is above normal windows. As a hack just for debugging, you could do something like this just *before* running the window as modal:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSApp.modalWindow.level = NSNormalWindowLevel;
});
```

Another approach would be to just run your app on a separate desktop space from Xcode.

Comment: First approach didn't work for me. I will try second one. (Seems promising.)